# How to refresh all in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My program opens a workbook specified by the user and returns values to the original workbook.

When I run the code, the workbook will not refresh. It does work when I debug/step-through the program.

```
Dim src As Workbook
Dim wkbk As String
' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK
wkbk = Range("A2").Value
Set src = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="S:\Engineering Team\Quoting\" & Range("A2").Value, ReadOnly:=True)
Workbooks(wkbk).RefreshAll
DoEvents
```

I tried a wait 5 seconds command, but this did not work. My background refresh is disabled so that is not the issue.

Comment: A side note, but why are you using `Workbooks(wkbk)` and not `src`, i.e. `src.RefreshAll`?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it does not change the functionality of the program

Comment: Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone after refreshAll ?

Comment: THIS WORKED!!!! Thanks so much. You have no idea the headache that was giving me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @ Vincent Farcy was correct!

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

The above was added after the refresh all command.

Answer (score 1):

Use **UpdateLinks** . If the constant is 0, it is not updated, and if it is 3, it is updated.

```
Sub test()
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim wkbk As String
    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK
    wkbk = Range("A2").Value
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="S:\Engineering Team\Quoting\" & Range("A2").Value, UpdateLinks:=3)
    
    DoEvents
End Sub
```